# Compiling directories with JavaCompiler

Tags: java, file, java-compiler-api

I have the following which code which is being used to compile single files with JavaCompiler:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(file.getAbsolutePath()));
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
boolean success = task.call();
fileManager.close();
```

My question is: How do I change this to compile all source files in a particular directory?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the files from the directory (using [directory.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)), and pass the resulting array to [getJavaFileObject(File...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html#getJavaFileObjects%28java.io.File...%29)

Comment: This gives me:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: directories not supported
 at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DefaultFileManager$RegularFileObject.<init>

Comment: Make sure to filter out the unwanted files using listFiles(FileFilter) : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29. You really need to learn reading the API doc. It's intended to be read.